# Azure Analytics : Kusto Query Dashboard group by client_CountryOrRegion and so whenever changing UTC time: past 24 hours it shows deviation in result

Tags: kql, azure-dashboard

```
pageViews
| where (url contains "https://***.com") 
| summarize TotalUserCount = dcount(user_Id)
| project TotalUserCount
```

Now when summarizing by client_CountryOrRegion, there is a deviation in result for different time range selected i.e. for 24 days, 2 days, 3 days, 7 days etc... User count by country does not match the total count. Is it due to UTC timezone?

```
pageViews
| where (url contains "https://***.com") 
| summarize Users= dcount(user_Id) by client_CountryOrRegion
```

Any help or suggestion would be like oxygen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the documentation of `dcount`:

> The dcount() aggregation function is primarily useful for **estimating** the cardinality of huge sets. **It trades performance for accuracy**, and may return a result that varies between executions. The order of inputs may have an effect on its output.

You can increase the accuracy of the estimation by providing the `accuracy` argument to `dcount`, e.g. `dcount(user_Id, 4)`. Note that this will improve the estimation (at the cost of query performance), but still won't be 100% accurate. You can read more about this in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dcount-aggfunction#estimation-accuracy).